# How can I use a list of values with the IN operator in a WHERE clause?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to execute a query like this, using the JavaScript driver:

```
client.execute('SELECT * FROM zhos_dev.jw_testing WHERE a IN ?', [['foo', 'foo1']], {prepare: true})
```

It gives me: `ResponseError: line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ')'`.

My version is: `[cqlsh 3.1.8 | Cassandra 1.2.19 | CQL spec 3.0.5 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]`

The table was created and populated with the following CQL:

```
CREATE TABLE zhos_dev.jw_testing (a text PRIMARY KEY, b text);
INSERT INTO zhos_dev.jw_testing (a, b) VALUES ('foo', 'bar');
INSERT INTO zhos_dev.jw_testing (a, b) VALUES ('foo1', 'bar1');
INSERT INTO zhos_dev.jw_testing (a, b) VALUES ('foo2', 'bar2');
```

Comment: This is a message related to a result error; there's not anything wrong with your formatting, at least in this line. Is "column1" part of your partition key? Can you share the table definition and connection string?

Comment: I've reproduced the problem using a new table created just now, with a simpler structure. See above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced this in the same version:
[cqlsh 3.1.8 | Cassandra 1.2.19 | CQL spec 3.0.5 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]

```
  name: 'ResponseError',
  info: 'Represents an error message from the server',
  message: "line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ')'",
  code: 8192,
  query: 'SELECT name, color FROM keyspace1.dresses WHERE id IN ?'
```

The "IN" clause works fine as early as Cassandra 2.1:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.21 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]

```
Connected to cluster with 1 host(s): ["127.0.0.1:9042"]
Azul Dress
```

Test table/data:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace1 WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

CREATE TABLE keyspace1.dresses (id text, color text, name text, size int, PRIMARY KEY (id, color));

insert into dresses (id, color, name, size) values ('mon1', 'blue', 'Blue Dress', 12);
insert into dresses (id, color, name, size) values ('mon2', 'blue', 'Azul Dress', 12);
insert into dresses (id, color, name, size) values ('can1', 'green', 'Green Dress', 12);
insert into dresses (id, color, name, size) values ('can2', 'verde', 'Verde Dress', 12);
```

And code:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');

const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], localDataCenter: 'datacenter1' });
client.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log('Connected to cluster with %d host(s): %j', client.hosts.length, client.hosts.keys());
});

client.execute('SELECT name, color FROM keyspace1.dresses WHERE id IN ?', [ ['mon2'] ], 
    { prepare: true}, 
    function (err, result) {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          const row = result.first();
          console.log(row['name']);
});
```

Since the node.js driver is only supported in Cassandra 2.1 and above (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.1/faq/#which-versions-of-cassandra-does-the-driver-support), I don't think the Cassandra or driver projects would take a bug request. Can you upgrade to at least 2.1?

Comment: Nice work!  And good tip about upgrading.  Nobody should have to suffer with a pre 2.1 Cassandra version anymore.

Comment: Excellent, I thought it was a version issue -- thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

This question is in the FAQ, but not in the documentation for the actual calls, and I couldn't find it easily on StackOverflow, so I thought I'd copy it here:

Quoting https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.1/faq/#how-can-i-use-a-list-of-values-with-the-in-operator-in-a-where-clause :

> use the IN operator followed by the question mark placeholder without parenthesis in the query. The parameter containing the list of values should be of an instance of Array.

Comment: Entertainly, when I try it, it gives me `ResponseError: line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ')'`